# Android Studio Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed `android-studio` in windows.But getting this error every time I rebuild/run/project.

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Below is what I have tried.

1. Disbaled firewall
2. `adb kill-server` && `adb start-server`
3. remove any adb process in the taskbar
4. restart studio, clean and rebuild

Any Answer is highly appreciated.

Comment: **goto:** tools-->android-->enable adb integration.( try this)

Comment: @BaratamNarendra Its already enabled.

Comment: are you using eclipse and android studio at same time(Parallely)?@nitesh

Comment: @BaratamNarendra nope

Answer (score 0):

Check if you don't have more than one adb.exe

```
where adb.exe
```

Comment: Please elaborate over your answer. That would be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

try run the build task from console, and check the output to see anything wrong

```
./gradle assembleDebug
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to-> Android Monitor Check your Device is properly connected.this type of error we get device not connected properly.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue was solved by **rebooting the computer**. It had just been resumed from hibernation when this error appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.I solved it by plugging in the usb cable of my moble phone to another port on my computer.